# Create a function to check execution time using explain analyze in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I ran some queries to get the execution time

The input query

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM employee emp where emp.empid = ' 00010   ';
```

The output result

```
"Seq Scan on employee emp  (cost=0.00..279.00 rows=1 width=90) (actual time=0.014..3.341 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (empid = ' 00010   '::bpchar)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 9999"
"Planning time: 0.066 ms"
"Execution time: 3.356 ms"
```

Then I wrote a function as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test19() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE total TEXT;
BEGIN
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE into total SELECT * FROM employee emp, payroll pr where emp.empid = ' 00010   ';
    RETURN total;
END;
```

But when I run the function

Input query

```
select * from test19()
```

The Output Result

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..543.00 rows=10000 width=108) (actual time=0.022..9.311 rows=10000 loops=1)
```

So the output from function doesn't contain the execution time. What is the mistake I have done above function?

Comment: Given that your function takes no inputs, why do you need a function here instead of using `EXPLAIN` directly?

Comment: The final outcome should be as follows

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test19(query TEXT, n INTEGER) RETURNS FLOAT AS $$
DECLARE total_time FLOAT;
DECLARE ex_time FLOAT
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 . . n
LOOP
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE query;
    -----Some  computation to extract execution time and save to ex_time------
    total := total + ex_time
END LOOP;
    RETURN total;
END;

so we need a function to input the query and no of executions and output should be the total execution time
eg:
select * from test19('Select * from table1', 1000) 
output should be like 1234ms

Comment: Say again what the **benefit** is when compared to direct `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, even with parameters? I can see you will get the same result **at best** but you seem to think it will make it better for some reason I cannot understand.

Comment: This procedure is used as we are asked to use the above method for assignment rather than directly using EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Answer (score 3):

You could return output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` as XML/JSON and parse it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test19() RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
DECLARE total TEXT;
BEGIN
    EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING, FORMAT JSON) into total SELECT 1 AS c;
    RETURN ((total::jsonb)-> 0 -> 'Execution Time');
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2c9d76b537aec486db1ea42ae061eb1d)**

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT INTO` in PL/pgSQL only processes a single row.

EXPLAIN returns multiple rows so your function only returns the first one.

If you only want to extract the execution time, you can either parse the JSON output as shown by Lukasz or you need a loop:

```
create or replace function show_time(to_explain text)
  returns text,
as
$$
declare
  l_plan_line record;
  l_line text;
begin
   l_line := 1;
   for l_plan_line in execute 'explain (analyze, verbose, format text)'||to_explain    
   loop
      l_line := l_plan_line."QUERY PLAN"::text;
      if l_line like 'Execution Time%' then 
         return l_line;
      end if;
   end loop;
   return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the below function, I can't believe it works ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test19(query TEXT) RETURNS JSON language 'plpgsql' AS $$
DECLARE total JSON;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, FORMAT JSON) ' || query into total;
    RETURN total;
END;
$$;
```

Here is an example as how to use it (with queries relevant on my db, replace with your own):

```
WITH Queries(q) AS (
    VALUES ('SELECT * FROM Price'),
    ('SELECT * FROM Price WHERE PriceTypeIK=2 AND PriceDate > current_date - interval ''50 days''')
)
SELECT q, (test19(q)->0->'Plan'->>'Actual Total Time')::FLOAT from queries;
```

Make sure you always use it in a transaction that you rollback, or savepoint, rollback to savepoint then commit.

Edit: Last comment I realized I did not write: you are not bound to extract the actual total time only, since I coded the function for it to return the entire plan. (try `SELECT q, test19(q) from queries` with the above).